# Delegate and method GetFunctionPointer

Tags: c#, delegates, function-pointers

I am trying to figure out why one of these delegates is working differently under the hood. I have basically these kind of delegates:

```
private delegate void _SetSomething(bool value);
private delegate Something _Find(string value);
private delegate T _AddSomething<T>();
```

For each of these I have to know the memory address where they are pointing out, so I used GetFunctionPointer and I got three addresses, nothing special right now except for the fact I have to patch these addresses in memory, so I checked them in disassembly view and I saw for the first two methods the expected behaviours but not for the last:

```
var obj = new SomethingObj();
obj.SetSomething(true); // E8 XX XX XX XX calling exactly the first address got from the delegate
firstDel.DynamicInvoke(true); // starts calling from the fp value
var ret1 = obj.Find("something"); // E8 XX XX XX XX calling exactly the second address from the delegate
var ret2 = secondDel.DynamicInvoke("something"); // starts calling from the fp value
var ret3 = obj.AddSomething<SomeStuff>(); // E8 XX XX XX XX !!! Here the address does not match with the function pointer got from delegate
var ret4 = thirdDel.DynamicInvoke(null); // starts calling from the fp value...
```

I am running out of the options, I don't completly understand what is happening with the last delegate except for the fact that it is a little bit more complex of the others.

I don't really understand why is not the same address called by the instance method like the others two, anyone could help me out?

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace Test
{
  internal class Program
  {
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var obj = new SomethingObj();

      var firstDel = (_SetSomething) Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof (_SetSomething), obj, "SetSomething");

      var targetFind = typeof (SomethingObj).GetMethod("Find");
      var secondDel = (_Find) Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof (_Find), obj, targetFind, true);

      var targetAdd = typeof (SomethingObj).GetMethods()
        .First(m => m.Name == "AddSomething" && m.GetParameters().Length == 0)
        .MakeGenericMethod(typeof (SomeStuff));
      var thirdDel =
        (_AddSomething<SomeStuff>) Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof (_AddSomething<SomeStuff>), obj, targetAdd, true);


      var firstAddress = firstDel.Method.MethodHandle.GetFunctionPointer();
      var secondAddress = secondDel.Method.MethodHandle.GetFunctionPointer();
      var thirdAddress = thirdDel.Method.MethodHandle.GetFunctionPointer();

      obj.SetSomething(true); // E8 XX XX XX XX calling exactly the first address got from the delegate
      firstDel.DynamicInvoke(true); // starts calling from the fp value
      var ret1 = obj.Find("something"); // E8 XX XX XX XX calling exactly the second address from the delegate
      var ret2 = secondDel.DynamicInvoke("something"); // starts calling from the fp value
      var ret3 = obj.AddSomething<SomeStuff>(); // E8 XX XX XX XX !!! Here the address does not match with the function pointer got from delegate
      var ret4 = thirdDel.DynamicInvoke(null); // starts calling from the fp value...
    }

    public class SomethingObj
    {
      public void SetSomething(bool value)
      {
      }

      public SomeStuff AddSomething(Type type)
      {
        return new SomeStuff();
      }

      public T AddSomething<T>() where T : SomeStuff
      {
        return new SomeStuff() as T;
      }

      public SomeStuff AddSomething(string className)
      {
        return new SomeStuff();
      }

      public SomeStuff Find(string value)
      {
        return new SomeStuff();
      }
    }

    public class SomeStuff
    {
    }

    public class SomeStuffTest : SomeStuff
    {
    }

    private delegate void _SetSomething(bool value);

    private delegate SomeStuff _Find(string value);

    private delegate T _AddSomething<T>();
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm finding it very hard to see what you're describing with only bits of the code. You've provided us the delegate *type declarations* but we have no idea how you obtained `firstDel`, `secondDel` or `thirdDel`, or what `SomethingObj` has. A [mcve] might help to clarify things...

Comment: You are right Jon, I am going to add some more code. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Sorry my fault I was editing the example directly in the post, now you should be able to compile it

Comment: Whopper of an XY question.  There is a mountain of code in the CLR that deals with delegates, it is ridiculously micro-optimized.  In general, the CLR auto-generates a sliver of machine code, a "stub", that captures the *this* object reference.  And, if necessary, deals with generics with different T producing different methods.  Different target objects and different T inevitably generate different stubs.  "patch these addresses in memory" is a highly elusive goal and unlikely to turn out well.

Comment: Thank @HansPassant, so tecnically is it almost impossible to realize a generic detour/hook for this type of delegate?

Comment: This stub seems align at fixed length, right now the only difference that I've noticed is between 32bit and 64bit arch. At least I've something working now also with this type of delegate, it is far from elegant and safe solution but it's doing its job. Thank you for the hints @HansPassant